# Blurred/disabled remote desktop session Windows 11?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

Blurred Remote Desktop:

[image: Blurred Remote Desktop]

My remote desktop session to one of my computer kind of freezes after being inactive a little while. Please see the attached image.I can still click the "disconnect" button but sending <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> etc does not bring up login screen. I have to disconnect and start a new session whenever this happens, and the session works fine after reconnection.

I have tried digging into event viewer logs, but not entirely sure where to even look for potential errors.

I have attempted connecting to this computer from two other computers running Windows 11 latest (patches/security and all), but the behavior is same. It makes me suspect that the problem is on the target computer - it is not the computer I am connecting from.

Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: To solve these issue for good, I essentially did a reinstall keeping data and programs hoping that termserv.dll might be repaired if it was somehow corrupted. I edited various settings in group policy. I finally created a new user and the remote desktop session does not behave the same for the newly created user..so this seems like a user specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I just put a $10 mouse jiggler to keep the session active…

Looks like I am the only person in the world who had this problem given no answer on this post.

Comment: You are allowed to tick it as the right answer after 24 hours.